# algorithms design and implementation

Tags: php, algorithm, jakarta-ee, design-patterns, architecture

What are the best resources of beginner to intermediate level that can help a software engineer grasp algorithms.

How they are written and what are the standards. What is the language of algorithms and how different are algorithms to pseudocode.

How to write good algorithms and algorithm design patterns.

Thanks.

Comment: Two books: Introduction to Algorithms and The Algorithm Design Manual (Springer)

Comment: @PauloBu Is there a link you can share with samples of pseudocode and algoriths that you could recommend?

Comment: sometimes you find good beginner courses on www.coursera.org

Comment: http://www.e-booksdirectory.com/details.php?ebook=1050 Algorithms and Data Structures free pdf download, on my reading list anyway ...

Comment: @OyugiK If you have trouble finding textbooks, you might want to try Library Genesis (http://libgen.org/ is the current URL, though it changes). I'll also second Paulo's "Algorithm Design Manual" recommendation.